# Bug report - Barcode : Side effect on the default font

Tags: java, pdf, itext

For the last 2 weeks I was a bit stuck by overlapping numbers characters that were inserted after a barcode.
I finally fixed it by specifying the desired font to all paragraphs

Code Working :

```
document.addCell(new Paragraph("1234", BASIC_FONT));
```

Code that had Overlaped / bad kerning Font :

```
document.addCell(new Paragraph("1234"));
```

To be honest I didn't go too deep into the source code of the library, but I think there is a side effect in the BarCode generation (you probably overwrite the default font of the whole document)

My solution : Restoring the default font after the barcode generation

Details :

- icepdf 5.0.2 (for rendering)
- iText 5.4.5
- barcode39

Code used for barcode generation

```
    Barcode39 myBarCode39 = new Barcode39();
    myBarCode39.setCode(myText);
    myBarCode39.setStartStopText(false);
    Image myBarCodeImage39 = myBarCode39.createImageWithBarcode(directContent, null, null);
    return myBarCodeImage39;
```

[Part of a pdf who got the problem](http://sd-24298.dedibox.fr/icePDF.png)

Best Regards

Comment: Are you sure you posted this to the right site? SO is for programming-related questions.

Comment: I think so: first people who got the same issue could use this solution, and the iText developping team is following stackoverflow

Comment: Which iText Version exactly did you observe that issue with?

Comment: I am sorry I just edit my post to add the iText version. I am using iText 5.4.5

Comment: Please provide a sample PDF (e.g. via a google or dropbox public share and post the URL here) and enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: The default font isn't changed by the barcode, so yes, I too would like to see a SSCCE.

Comment: @mkl : I am going to do it today, hold on for the code sample and the pdf (I obviously can't share the whole project)

Comment: *hold on for the code sample and the pdf* - hhmmm, I guess I'll stop holding my breath waiting for that... ;)